# Como evitar a lotação da memória em SELECT grande no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gerenciamento-de-memória, active-record

Na rotina que estou desenvolvendo, faço um SELECT simples no banco, apenas em uma tabela:

```
Model.select("id").where(:tipo => 2).find_each do |registro|
    puts registro.id
end
```

Mas este select retorna em torno de 160.000 registros. Aí o sistema dá o erro:

> pid 258 SIGKILL (signal 9)

Se eu comentar esta linha e seguir o meu código, tudo roda normalmente. Já pesquisei sobre isso e comecei a usar a função `find_each` no lugar de `each`, mas o erro continuou. Se eu limitar a query, também funciona normalmente.

Pelo que entendi, o erro é somente por conta do volume de dados que é maior do que a memória pode suportar. Analisando http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches e https://www.webascender.com/blog/rails-tips-speeding-activerecord-queries/, observei que o `find_each` melhora essa situação, mas não adiantou. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Vai na linha de comando na pasta do seu projeto Rails e digita `rails console`. Vai abrir um terminal parecido com o `irb`. Lá você roda `Model.select("id").where(:tipo => 2)` e vê a query SQL que está sendo gerada. Edita a pergunta inserindo essa query.

Comment: Quanto vc tem de memória? Qual S.O ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você esteja precisando do método **find_in_batches**. Ele quebra a sua consulta em consultas com menores intervalos de registro. Dessa maneira você não sobrecarrega sua memória com o Rails tentando mapear todas as linhas em objetos em memória.

Exemplo:

```
Model.select("id").where(:tipo => 2).find_in_batches do |registro|
  puts registro.id
end
```

Por padrão ele busca 1000 registros. Normalmente essa quantidade é tranquila mas se você tiver o mesmo problema com essa quantidade você pode customizar setando a opção **batch_size**.

```
Model.select("id").where(:tipo => 2).find_in_batches(batch_size: 500) do |registro|
  puts registro.id
end
```

[Confere na API para mais detalhes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches)